# TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced

Tags: numpy, matrix

can you please help me correct the below given code ?

Input:

`R`: the rating matrix, a float numpy matrix of shape m by n. If the rating is unknown, the number is None.

Output:

`B`: the binary masking matrix, a float numpy matrix of shape m by n.

- if `R[i, j]` is not missing, `B[i, j] = 1`
- if `R[i, j]` is missing (None), `B[i, j] = 0`

[code]

```
def compute_B(R):
    for (i, j), value in np.ndenumerate(R):
        if R[i, j] == None:
           R[i, j] = 0
        else:
            R[i, j] = 1

    B = R
    return B
```

Comment: Missing numbers are None or NaN?

Comment: some of the elements in the numpy array is 'None'

Comment: @VishawV. That means you don't have a floating array. Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. here bro,  R = np.array( [ [   4.,   5.,   3., None,   1.],
                    [ None,   2.,   3.,   2.,   3.],
                    [   5., None,   1.,   2., None]])

Comment: Hi, I solved the problem. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If `R` is indeed a floating point array, it can contain `nan` elements, not `None`. You don't need a loop to create a mask of a numpy array:

```
B = ~np.isnan(R)
```

Comment: Hi, it now says ufunc: 'isnan' not supported for the input types. The test case for R is a numpy array with 'None' as element in certain places and numbers in the other places.

Comment: @VishawV. What is the dtype?

Answer (score 0):

[code]

```
def compute_B(R):

    B = R != None
    B = B.astype(int)

    return B
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [160]: R = np.array( [ [ 4., 5., 3., None, 1.], [ None, 2., 3., 2., 3.], [ 5.
     ...: , None, 1., 2., None]])                                               
In [161]: R                                                                     
Out[161]: 
array([[4.0, 5.0, 3.0, None, 1.0],
       [None, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0],
       [5.0, None, 1.0, 2.0, None]], dtype=object)
```

This is an array of python objects, some are numbers, some `None`.

```
In [162]: list(np.ndenumerate(R))                                               
Out[162]: 
[((0, 0), 4.0),
 ((0, 1), 5.0),
 ((0, 2), 3.0),
 ((0, 3), None),
 ((0, 4), 1.0),
 ((1, 0), None),
 ((1, 1), 2.0),
 ((1, 2), 3.0),
 ((1, 3), 2.0),
 ...
 ((2, 4), None)]
In [163]: for (i,j),k in np.ndenumerate(R): 
     ...:     if k is None: 
     ...:         R[i,j] = 0 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         R[i,j] = 1 
     ...:                                                                       
In [164]: R                                                                     
Out[164]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=object)
```

`is None` is the correct test when expecting `None`.

Another way of doing the test:

```
In [167]: np.frompyfunc(lambda k: k is None, 1,1)(R)                            
Out[167]: 
array([[False, False, False, True, False],
       [True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, True, False, False, True]], dtype=object)
In [168]: np.where(np.frompyfunc(lambda k: k is None, 1,1)(R),0,1)              
Out[168]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Or including the 0/1 assignment in the lambda:

```
In [169]: np.frompyfunc(lambda k: 0 if k is None else 1, 1,1)(R)                
Out[169]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Looks like `astype(float)` converts the `None` to `nan`:

```
In [177]: R.astype(float)                                                       
Out[177]: 
array([[ 4.,  5.,  3., nan,  1.],
       [nan,  2.,  3.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 5., nan,  1.,  2., nan]])
In [178]: np.isnan(R.astype(float))                                             
Out[178]: 
array([[False, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True]])
In [179]: np.where(np.isnan(R.astype(float)),0,1)                               
Out[179]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: @hapulj, yeah this makes total sense and works perfectly fine. Thank you.